# FormatConvertedBitmap with alpha

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a problem in WPF. I'm making a delete button with an image in it. When the button is disabled, however, I wanted to display a greyscale image.

I found the [Thomas Lebrun implementation](http://weblogs.asp.net/thomaslebrun/wpf-how-to-gray-the-icon-of-a-menuitem), but I don't want to add the whole class in my program. Instead I tried to mimic the behavior in this way:

```
BitmapImage img_Delete = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("the png URI", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
ImageSource img_DeleteDisabled = null;

[...]
Button btDel = new Button() { Width = 20, Height = 20, ToolTip = "Delete", Margin = new Thickness(5), HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right };
btDel.IsEnabled = isdeletable(obj);

if (!btDel.IsEnabled && (img_DeleteDisabled == null))
{
    img_DeleteDisabled = new FormatConvertedBitmap(img_Delete, PixelFormats.Gray32Float, null, 0);
}

btDel.Content = (new System.Windows.Controls.Image()
{
    Width = 16,
    Height = 16,
    HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
    VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
    Source = btDel.IsEnabled ? img_Delete : img_DeleteDisabled
});
```

It behaves in the expected way, except.. Well, I'll show you:

[image: Enabled and disabled]

The left one is enabled, the right one is disabled

As you can see the alpha channel is gone. How can I integrate it back?

Comment: what is alpha channel?

Comment: alpha channel includes transparency information: in the left the red cross has a transparent background, while the grey one has a black one..

Comment: try to set `btDel.Background = Brushes.Transparent;`

Comment: @StepUp Nope.. The button should keep its grey background, the image should have transparent instead of the black. If I put that, the grey behind the red cross goes away, and the black square remains

Comment: In referenced example mentioned about `OpacityMask`. You can try to use it `img_DeleteDisabled.OpacityMask = new ImageBrush(img_Delete);`

Comment: @bars222 the problem is that `ImageSource` does not contain `OpacityMask`; in fact the author inherits from `Image`. But the `Source` property of the button content can't be an `Image`; if I put `img_DeleteDisabled.Source = ...` and `img_DeleteDisabled.OpacityMask = new ImageBrush(bitmapImage);`, like in the example, then I'm forced to use `Source = btDel.IsEnabled ? img_Delete : img_DeleteDisabled.Source`, which does not use `OpacityMask`

Comment: So can you set `OpacityMask` in the `Image` constructor (like setting `Source`)?

Comment: The problem is not with the `Image` itself, but rather with the fact I need to pass `img_DeleteDisabled.Source` if it is an `Image`, and so there is no opacity mask (since `img_DeleteDisabled.Source` does not have opacity masks associated)

Comment: maybe you need to delete black background of your image using some paint editor?

Comment: @StepUp The original image (the png one) was already without background. I needed this because I did not want to add a new greyscale image for every image I have, but rather to have the program "calculate" it. In this calculation, however, the transparent background became black. Anyway I solved it (see my answer)

Comment: @bars222 It looks that the opacity mask should be set in the button itself, not in the image source.. See my answer for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helped by the comments, I figured out I was thinking about the wrong place where to apply the opacity mask.

The `OpacityMask` should be applied to the button, not to the image. This is because the opacity applies to the whole image rather than its source.

For this reason, the correct way to implement this is

```
btDel.Content = (new System.Windows.Controls.Image()
{
    Width = 16,
    Height = 16,
    HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
    VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
    Source = btDel.IsEnabled ? img_Delete : img_DeleteDisabled,
    OpacityMask = new ImageBrush(img_Delete)
});
```

This way the mask is applied to the button image. The result is what I needed:

[image: Enabled and disabled]

Comment: I'm glad that my suggestion is helped and setting the `OpacityMask` like `Source` is helped, maybe I'm not clear in the comment (I'm wrote in image constructor, but meaning initializing code).

Comment: @bars222 actually I did not think about the button content as an `Image`, so I thought you were saying to use it in the `img_DeleteDisabled = new Image` constructor... Sorry

Comment: It's ok, finally we're found the solution.